# Use contents of string variable to call function

Tags: php

I have the following piece of code

```
copy($source, $target);
```

I also use

```
move_uploaded_file($source, $target);
```

To prevent code reuse, I want to pass copy and move_uploaded_file in via a variable.

If my variable is `$var = "copy";`, simply putting `$var($source, $target);`, doesn't seem to work.

Are there any special characters that must surround `$var`?

Thanks.

Comment: If it doesn't work, then what does it do? Error? Warning? Nothing?

Comment: "To prevent code reuse" - You sure that's what you meant? ;)

Comment: @nickb - I'm using the same function 2/3 times for an image upload but the final call to the function must move the image and not copy it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct syntax is `$var` ([variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)), so your code should work.

But please don't do that, just write the code in a straightforward and readable manner. There *are* legitimate use cases for this technique, but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at [Variable Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) which goes on to explain how to do that.

```
function foo() {
    echo "In foo()<br />\n";
}
$bar = 'foo';
$bar(); //this calls foo()
```

This can also be done on both object methods and static methods.

**Object Methods**

```
class Foo
{
    function MyFunction()
    {
        //code here
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$funcName = "MyFunction";
$foo->$funcName();
```

**Static Methods**

```
class Bar
{
    static function MyStaticFunction()
    {
        //code here
    }
}

$funcName = "MyStaticFunction";
Bar::$funcName();
```

While maybe not the case in your situation, when dealing with functions dynamically like this, it is important to check whether the [function actually exists](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) and/or [is callable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php).

Alternatively to using Variable Functions, you can use [`call_user_func`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) which will call the function based on the string name and with provided parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP function call_user_func().

[More info here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `call_user_func` to do this.

```
 $result = call_user_func($functionToCall, $source, $target)
```

Documentation: [PHP: call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know your code should work

here is the link for [your refrence](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)